# How to force click in cxDBButtonEdit?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I, have many cxDBButtonEdit in my form, and I want, when the user press ENTER make a click in the first button.

I try to find any methods, procedure, function.. and nothing!

I try to make like this:

```
if (ActiveControl is TcxDBButtonEdit) then
    begin
      if ((ActiveControl as TcxDBButtonEdit).Properties.Buttons.Count > 0) and ((ActiveControl as TcxDBButtonEdit).Properties.Buttons.Items[0].Enabled) then
      begin
        (ActiveControl as TcxDBButtonEdit) <----- HERE
        try
          GetParentForm(Screen.ActiveForm).Perform(CM_DIALOGKEY, VK_TAB, 0);
          Key := #0;
        except
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You're working much too hard. :-)

Your question asks about clicking the button, but your code indicates sending a tab (VK_TAB). I'm not sure which you're actually wanting to do, so I'll try to address both.

I don't know anything about the TcxDBButtonEdit (or any of the other DevExpress controls), but something like this should work for you (for the tab key):

```
if (ActiveControl is TcxDBButtonEdit) then
begin
  // We know it's a TcxDBButtonEdit, so we can directly cast it
  if (TcxDBButtonEdit(ActiveControl).Properties.Buttons.Count > 0) and 
     (TcxDBButtonEdit(ActiveControl.Properties.Buttons.Items[0].Enabled) then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    Self.SelectNext(ActiveControl, True, True); // See notes below
  end;
end;
```

If you're wanting to actually click the button attached to the edit control, [DevExpress support has an article](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q477013) that says that you can do this to invoke the button's click handler (replace the call to `SelectNext` above):

```
if (ActiveControl is TcxDBButtonEdit) then
begin
  // We know it's a TcxDBButtonEdit, so we can directly cast it
  if (TcxDBButtonEdit(ActiveControl).Properties.Buttons.Count > 0) and 
     (TcxDBButtonEdit(ActiveControl.Properties.Buttons.Items[0].Enabled) then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    TcxCustomEditAccess(ActiveControl).DoButtonClick(0);
  end;
end;
```

(I clearly can't compile the above code, because I don't have the DevEx controls; the line calling `DoButtonClick` is from their article. If the compiler complains about it, you probably need to add the following to your code (right above the method containing the code that uses it is probably the best place):

```
type
  TcxCustomEditAccess = class(TCxCustomEdit);
```

From the 'Access' part of the name, it looks like the `DoButtonClick` might be a protected method of the `TcxCustomEdit`. Declaring the interposer class allows you access to the protected method.)

Notes about SelectNext:

From the [TWinControl.SelectNext](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.SelectNext) documentation

> Moves the input focus from the current child control to the next one in the tab order.
>
> Call SelectNext to move the child control focus. SelectNext selects the first child that follows or precedes CurControl in the tab order and that meets the criteria specified in the other parameters.
>
> The GoForward parameter controls the direction of the search. If GoForward is true, FindNextControl searches forward through the child controls in tab order. If GoForward is false, SelectNext searches backward through the controls. The search wraps past the end of the collection back to CurControl.
>
> The CheckTabStop parameter controls whether the control SelectNext finds must be a tab stop. If CheckTabStop is true, the returned control must have its TabStop property set to true, or the search for the next control continues.
>
> If a child control matches the search criteria, that control obtains the focus. If no such child control is found, the focus remains unchanged.

Comment: I don't think that *"make a click"* means focusing the next control. But who knows :-) Besides, I believe that the button inside that control either displays some DB items editor or executes some other  action which could be invoked directly without faking a click event.

Comment: @TLama: The code in the original question shows sending a tab key (VK_TAB), which is what I presumed the intent was despite the title. As I said, I'm not familiar with the control; I haven't used them since about a decade ago (when I was at a job that did).

Comment: Hi, my original code, on "HERE" in my code, I try to make a Click on the button. After Make a click on the button, I simulate a TAB press. Sorry for the misunderstand..

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your reply, but I have other problem. When I press ENTER, doesn't call the code, I think because of this: **if (ActiveControl is TcxDBButtonEdit) then** The component is not recognized as TcxDBButtonEdit, how can I fix this? Any ideia?

Comment: @fh_bash: Well, you could start by finding out what the `ActiveControl.ClassName` is, right?

Comment: @KenWhite Before I reply I try that, but show me: Inaccessible value  Any Thoughts?

Comment: Where are you seeing that? You should just do something like 'if (ActiveControl is TcxDBButtonEdit) then...end else ShowMessage(ActiveControl.ClassName);`. You only need to see it once, and then you can remove the `else ShowMessage`. It's only for trying to figure out why things aren't working.